# How to reset a WSO2 Carbon Datasource to take a new user without restarting the server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there a way to reset a WSO2 Carbon Datasource, for example if I need to  change the username, without restarting the server?

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the username of the data source without restarting if it is configured from a file such as master-datasources.xml file. But if it is configured in the registry, you can change them.

Comment: It's not added to the master-datasources.xml, it's added by the carbon datasources Configure Menu. I can change it, but, Can I restart only the Datasource? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, You can restart the database.

Comment: I can't restart the database. The only thing that I need, it's a way to reset the connections of a Datasource without restart wso2 ei. Thanks.